# Which component of OpenAZ is executing "Obligations" in XACML

Tags: xacml, balana

I'm using OpenAZ project to process an XACML policy.
I need to know which component of OpenAZ is used to execute Obligations, How can I find it knowing that I have the source code. The documentation is not clear about this point (or I may have missed it).

Thanks !

Comment: Ask your question on the OpenAZ mailing list. You'll get a better answer there: http://lists.openliberty.org/mailman/listinfo/openaz

Comment: Thanks for the idea but no one answred me..